# Eclipse: Maven: error: not found: type SparkConf

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I'm trying to execute a Spark/Scala code snippet (given below) in Eclipse. I have created a Maven project for it but I'm getting the following error when I try to run the code:

```
not found: type SparkConf
```

My code is:

```scala
package extraction

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object JsonParser {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark json extract")
    conf.setMaster("local");
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val df = sqlContext.read.json("F:\\test1.json")
        df.registerTempTable("jsonExtract")
        val data = sqlContext.sql("select * from jsonExtract")
        data.show();
        sc.stop
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>JSON</groupId>
      <artifactId>JSON</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration> 
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

How I can fix this error? Is it not possible to build this project in Eclipse?

Comment: You have everything under `<build></build>` I don't think Maven can read your dependencies that way.

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: You also have your dependencies inside of `plugins`, which is not correct

Comment: And you're not using the Scala Maven Compiler plugin, plus a really old version of Spark

Comment: @philantrovert When I am adding `dependencies` outside `build` then its showing error in `pom.xml`

Comment: Please go through the maven docs as suggested in the answer below. It should be `<project>  <dependencies> < dependency> </dependency> </dependencies> </project>`

Comment: @philantrovert I have updated pom.xml in my question and now `pom.xml` has downloaded the `dependencies` but the `SparkConf` error is still exist

Comment: @cricket_007 Please tell me the `plugin`. What I have to give inside the `plugin`?

Comment: You can search for things on your own, but https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html

Comment: Or you can just start over, and use a Maven archetype, which sets everything up for you. https://github.com/spark-in-action/scala-archetype-sparkinaction

Answer (score 1):

I think your `<dependencies> </dependencies>` tag is missing.  [See Maven POM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies)

**Edit:**

It could be also repository issue. Check you have the right libs in your repos:

- [Maven repository schema](https://maven.apache.org/repository/index.html) - [Maven Central repositories](https://mvnrepository.com/)
- [Local repos](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/). Maven checks central repos but it compiles with libs you have in local.